# How to write a Service Mapping Description file?

Tags: rpc, json-rpc

i've got a json-rpc server running and i'm trying to write a client in Perl with RPC::JSON and i also want to expose the methods to other users so apparently i need an SMD file, for which i can't find a specification or guidelines.

Is this the usual method to expose json-rpc services?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, SMD files are not in wide use.  You certainly dont have to provide an SMD file to enable other people to user your interface.  Most Json-RPC client tools will let you talk to any API, documented or not.

Answer (score 1):

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/rpc/smd.html

It's a lot like WSDL; you can call services without it, but it serves as a reference and can be used by tools to generate a more convenient wrapper.

Comment: Is there any documentation for SMD, except this  ?